# is it possible email both html and excel in microstrategy

Tags: microstrategy

Can we schedule emails for a group of users with both excel and html in one email?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MicroStrategy out of the box doesn't allow you to have two attachments or to attach an excel and also the data in HTML in the email body.

You can try to send two different emails (probably you already thought of it) or you need some ad-hoc solution for your case. I think your possibilities are:

1. Write some SDK code for MSTR to export the Excel and the HTML files and then send them.
2. Export the files to a disk location with a schedule and have an external script to create and send one single email every time the files are refreshed.

Then first solution (more complicated to implement) can read the addresses from MicroStrategy, the second one (easier) probably will require that the list of subscribers is maintained also outside MicroStrategy.